# Mysql send info from slave to master

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication

We have big data project. We have **two servers**, one for parsing information, and second is for our website.

1. First server is: parser server / data collecting (MySQL Master)
2. Second server is: website server (MySQL Slave)

**The problem is**, we have mysql slave needs to change few records now and then. **How can we sync that info back to master** ?

The query is very simple and looks like this:

```
UPDATE domains SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = $DOMAIN_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to make your first server a slave of the second server as well, giving you what is referred to as a master-master replication setup.

So instead of this:

db1 -> db2

You have this:

db1 <-> db2

In order for that to work you need to make sure the two servers each have a unique `server_id` value, both of them have binary logging enabled, and you should either disable the `read_only` option on the second server (if it's currently enabled), or do the updates on the second server with a user who has `super` privilege.